# Hide DataGrid borders (or what left of it)

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I don't really know how to describe it. Best thing is to show it:
[image: DataGrid with funny border problem]

Do you see those thin black lines?
Here is Xaml snippet:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding RunnedTests}" Margin="5"
              HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsEnabled="False"
              GridLinesVisibility="None" RowBackground="#FF268AEC" BorderBrush="#FF268AEC" BorderThickness="0">            
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="4*" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PassedOrFailed}" Width="*">                    
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />                            
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPassed}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />                                    
                            </DataTrigger>                                
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The BorderBrush & BorderThickness doesn't really do anything for it. Without those properties it will stay the same.

Here is a Picture of the same DataGrid without the RowBackground property:
[image: DataGrid without RowBackground property]

More notes:

1. Background property of DataGrid does nothing
2. I don't know if you can see from my code, but hides there a frustrating struggle with DataTrigger. I wanted to display the words "passed" or "failed" depending on the IsPassed bool property via DataTrigger, but could not make it. At the end I had to compromise and create the property PassedOrFailed in the model. It is quite stupid in my point of view, can you suggest a way to accomplish it?

Thanks!

### Update:

I forgot to mention two additional styles:

```
 <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />            
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />            
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    </Style>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: How do I hide those shadow like fine lines on the first picture?

Comment: Ok I see.  Before I get into it, have you tried just using a ListBox?  You're not generating columns.  It seems like a better way to go.

Comment: Much better indeed! Thanks